# uncaught reference error function is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, mean

I'm trying to make a quiz application implementing an increase if the right answer is clicked. I already know which answer is the right answer, but I want to make it so if you click the radio button it will increase the right answer counter. I'm trying to use a method called correctTest to implement, but it is saying that I'm not defining it. Any ideas?

```
$scope.correctTest = function($index) {
    if(document.getElementById("option+$index").checked){
        $http.put('quizQuestions', {
            _id: _id,
            isRight: 1
        })
    }
};
```

and the call to it is in a button.

```
<input type="radio" name="option1+{{question._id}}" id="option1" value="option1" onclick="correctTest($index)">
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you are in the correct controller and app?

if yes..
 use `ng-click`

```
<input type="radio" id="option1" value="option1" ng-click="correctTest($index)"/>correct test
```